# CCM_DPISCALE common control message

Tags: winapi

I've been updating an existing Win32 app to be DPI aware. Following various guides on MSDN and other sites, I manually scale my coordinates and font sizes according to the current monitor DPI.

I just stumbled upon this message: [CCM_DPISCALE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/Controls/ccm-dpiscale/). The docs say:

> Enables automatic high dots per inch (dpi) scaling in Tree-View
>   controls, List-View controls, ComboBoxEx controls, Header controls,
>   Buttons, Toolbar controls, Animation controls, and Image Lists

But what does it actually *do*? I try sending the message to my control like so:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, CCM_DPISCALE, (WPARAM) TRUE, 0);
```

But it has no discernible effect on font, size, layout - anything, at any DPI.

I am using `Comclt32.dll` version 6.0, as per the documentation.

The only reference I can find to this message when Googling it is that MSDN page, and a link from the [LVCOLUMNA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taglvcolumna) documentation.

What is this message actually supposed to do?

Comment: Don't know what the message does, but found [a source file where it's used](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/blob/df2c8905b73ad9c0cda865369d945b2f1044dcbf/decoder/LAVAudio/AudioSettingsProp.cpp#L677). Do you have a compatibility section in your manifest? System may ignore the message if you don't specify compatibility with specific OS versions.

Comment: In my .exe headers, I have: `6.00 operating system version 6.00 subsystem version`

Comment: Not what I meant. [_Targeting your application for Windows_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1).

Comment: @zett42 interesting, thanks. The link only talks about manifesting for Windows 8 and up. Since CCM_DPISCALE is (allegedly!) supported since Vista, I'm not sure that can be related?

Comment: The sample manifest includes Vista too.

Comment: @zett42 Ok, yes, sorry I see that now. I note that the manifest docs also say `Application manifests without a compatibility element default to Windows Vista compatibility`. I tried it regardless; no noticeable change :) Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Whatever it was intended for, it's not necessary if your app is flagged as being dpi-aware.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, that's what I thought. I made my app DPI aware quite a while back (I forget the exact details now) and all the Windows controls 'just worked'.

Comment: @PaulSanders except for the 1% that doesn't "just work". For example, ListView control empty markup or report style group headers don't get scaled automatically and I have no control over them, unless I owner-draw the whole thing.

Comment: Oh right, typical, nice to know (especially about the header control), although I don't currently use either of those.  Was the "ListView control empty markup font" thing your post?  I guess it must have been.  Still casting around then, but perhaps you can just stick a dummy entry in there saying "the list is currently empty" and get away with that.  And presumably you can set the font used by the header control (and change the height?) yourself.  Something along those lines, anyhow.

Comment: @PaulSanders For the header, I'm specifically talking about the "group" header in a report-style list view (not the column header), where it's not possible to set the font. And for sure I can workaround the empty markup in the list view (yes, that question was me!). Coming from a Cocoa background where this stuff truly does "just work", I just get bemused when I hit these 1% issues in Win32. So when I see something like CCM_DPISCALE, I think that maybe I missed something that everybody else already knows about :)

Comment: Ah, you mean [these guys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Controls/list-view-controls-overview#arranging-list-items-by-group).  Sorry, my mistake.  You're stuck there then, I guess.  Owner drawing the whole thing would be a pain.  Cocoa sure is light years ahead of Win32 - Apple bit the bullet back when they bought Next back in the day and did the job properly.  It's never been clear to me what the best option is to escape the clutches of the now-ancient Win32 GUI 'framework', especially if you want something that works cross-platform (which is a requirement for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out at least a small part of what this does.

In a `ListView` control, if columns are created with fixed width (`LVCFMT_FIXED_WIDTH`) and as long as you don't specify `LVCFMT_NO_DPI_SCALE`, `CCM_DPISCALE` will scale the column width according to the current DPI.

If you have a grouped `LVS_REPORT` style `ListView`, and the group header contains an image (`LVGF_TITLEIMAGE`) that image will also be scaled (but *not* the group text (`LVGF_HEADER`))

I didn't test if this scaling is per monitor or not, and I didn't find anything else that this message does (although as per my question, it is documented to effect multiple controls). I am interested in finding out what else this message does!